# wrong architecture for erlang runtime?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, erlang

I'm playing around with http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html on OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard. and I'm having some trouble running the example.

I compile using :

```
gcc -o complex_nif.so -fpic -I/usr/local/lib/erlang/usr/include -flat_namespace -undefined suppress complex.c complex_nif.c
```

and run in erlang using:

```
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c(complex).
{error,on_load_failure}

=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Apr-2013::15:24:51 ===
Error in process <0.37.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(./complex_nif.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n      ./complex_nif.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture'"}}},[{complex,init,0,[{file,"... 


=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Apr-2013::15:24:51 ===
The on_load function for module complex returned {{badmatch,
                                                   {error,
                                                    {load_failed,
                                                     "Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(./complex_nif.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t./complex_nif.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture'"}}},
                                                  [{complex,init,0,
                                                    [{file,...},{...}]},
                                                   {code_server,
                                                    '-handle_on_load/4-fun-0-',
                                                    1,
                                                    [{...}|...]}]}
```

I see that I'm finding the .so file. but erlang does not like the achitecture that it had been compiled for, what architecture would erlang prefer?

Comment: @RobertoAloi, I've tried both -m32 and -m64, none of them made any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Verify the architecture used by your Erlang Run Time System. E.g.:

```
$ which erlc
/usr/local/bin/erlc
$ file /usr/local/bin/erlc
/usr/local/bin/erlc: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Ensure your library matches the above architecture:

```
$ file complex_nif.so
complex_nif.so: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

If they do not match, compile the library with the `-arch i386` (or `-arch x86_64`) flag.

Comment: The do match.. sorta `complex.so: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386` and `/usr/local/bin/erlc: Mach-O executable i386`

Comment: I made them match completely -- still the same error..

Comment: Can you show the entire sequence of compilation commands, relative errors and output for `file` commands?

Comment: I don't think this question is too localized and voted for reopen, Roberto can you vote too?